# does Cloud Firestore realtime listener get all document from server when only one document change?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my code I have listener that listen to 7 document.

```
Firestore.firestore()
            .collection(FirestorePaths.days)
            .whereField(DayKeys.date, in: CalendarService.shared.currentWeek)
            .whereField(DayKeys.fieldId, isEqualTo: "JAfWuBindnh4jIfsVGh4Vl3AvfU2")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                
                querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                           if (diff.type == .added) {
                               print("New day: \(diff.document.data())")
                           }
                           if (diff.type == .modified) {
                               print("Modified day: \(diff.document.data())")
                           }
                           if (diff.type == .removed) {
                               print("Removed day: \(diff.document.data())")
                           }
                       }
                
                _ = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap {
                    print($0.metadata.isFromCache ? "Cache" : "Server")
                }
                
            }
```

but when one document change from server side i get this message:

```
Modified day ...

    Server
    Server
    Server
    Server
    Server
    Server
    Server
```

**so I'm wondering does its count 7 read or only one read?**

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that changes that single document, that you were talking about.

Comment: actually document change from another client, I get one modified message but get server message for every document i am monitoring

Comment: Are you sure you aren't updating all documents?

Comment: I am sure, because i am getting only one modifying message

Comment: So you basically say that you are notified with 7 documents when only one is changed?

Comment: yeah the listener will return you all 7 documents I guess!

Comment: @AlexMamo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aoxOtMM2rc&ab_channel=Firebase see minute 1:25 firestore documentation says that all document return but you get paid for one read .. but all document meta data says from sever so its a strange !

Answer (score 1):

When any document for your snapshot listener changes, your code gets called again with a query snapshot with all documents, but you only get charged for the documents that had to be read from/on the server for that. So if only one document changed, you'll only get charged for that one document.

The `metadata` field `isFromCache` is confusingly named, but actually signals where the document snapshot may contain data that is not up to date with the server. So it's better to read it as "may contain stale data", which is not the case here for any of the documents.

Comment: so for my example its 1 charge or 7 ?

Comment: if only one document changed, you'll only get charged for that one document